# In Power Grid, what are the phases and what are the steps?

Tags: power-grid, terminology

My copy of Power Grid has an strange reversal of terminology between the cards:

[image: Power Grid "Phase 3" and summary cards]

... and the rules:

[image: Power Grid rules excerpt]

Obviously this isn't a huge deal, but I just wonder which is correct in terms of the other editions of the game available?

---

*Update:* after the answer below confirmed that the cards are wrong rather than the rules, I contacted [Rio Grande Games](http://www.riograndegames.com/) to ask about getting replacement cards.  They directed me to the [BoardGameGeek store](https://boardgamegeekstore.com), which sells a Power Grid promotional pack called ["Power Grid: Theme Park (BGG Promo Card Set)"](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/88491/power-grid-bgg-promo-card-set).  This contains a replacement Step 3 card, but sadly no replacement player summary cards...  If anyone knows how to get them, that would be great to know.

Comment: Power grid's terminology is totally backwards from what it should be.  Phases should be bigger than steps.  I would love to have cards that refer to phases rather than steps because it would make the game so much easier to explain.

Comment: @Zags It's simply a bad translation. The German word *Stufe* can be translated into English as *step* or *stage* - whoever translated the rules should have picked the second one instead of the first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In later revisons of Power Grid phases are used to describe the difference phases of a turn. Steps are used to describe the 3 different game states that happens when a player builds 7 cities or pull the card in OP post from the top of the power plant pile.

The card does say "Step 3" in the later revisions that I played.

For more information check the [Power Grid FAQ](http://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Power_Grid_FAQ#toc46)

Comment: This is correct, I believe it was a simple mistranslation on the card. Personally, I think they should have fixed it the other way – making the game have three "phases" and outlining the five "steps" of each turn, but what's done is done. :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, FuleSnabel.  @ghoppe: I'd agree that in English it would make more sense for the phases to be the longer period!  Thanks for mentioning the translation issue - I see that indeed in Funkenschalg, each round is made up of 5 Phasen, and the 3 periods that the game is divided up into are Stufen.